# linearlayout is not displaying properly

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have created this main XML file in my project. I have parsed XML file and displayed dynamically in linear layout1. But linearlayout2 is not displaying in my result. please help me. This is my main XML file . I am using one XML file to display my widgets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true" >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="Signature" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="Submit" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy and paste this layout, its modified by adding layout_weight in your scroll view and linearlayout2 to equally distribute the screen. Hope it fulfills your requirements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="Signature" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="Submit" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you use relative layout for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think its easy to solve:

Your ScrollView defines the layout height to "wrap-content", it means 
"childs can take all needed space". but, in the first child you define the height
as "match_parent". it means "i need most of space as i can get".

To solve the problem, simply let the height of the linearlayout within the ScrollView
"0dip" and set the layout_weight to "1".